# Java: How to ask user if he/she wants to continue program

Tags: java

I've already made it so that it will tell whether the input from the user is a prime number or not a prime number but now I have to make it so that it will ask the user if he/she wants to check another number and wait for the user to enter "Y" or "y" as yes, "n" or "N" as no. If yes, repeat the three steps. If no, exit the program. For all other letters, reject ti and ask the user to enter only "y" or "n".

```
import java.util.*;  // importing package util


public class Prime
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        int num,count=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input
        System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i <= (num/2); i++) 
        {
            if((num % i) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if((count==0) && (num!= 1))
        System.out.println( num + " is a prime number.");
        else
        System.out.println( num + " is not a prime number.");
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were able to code up what you show, the rest of it should be quite easy, have you tried?

Comment: Start by taking a look at [do-while](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loops

Comment: @MadProgrammer : Exactly. Boy, this takes me back.

Answer (score 3):

This is a pretty standard way I learnt when I started coding.

Use a `do-while` loop like this:

```
do
{
 System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i <= (num/2); i++) 
        {
            if((num % i) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if((count==0) && (num!= 1))
        System.out.println( num + " is a prime number.");
        else
        System.out.println( num + " is not a prime number.");
        System.out.println("Continue(Y/N)");
        char a = scan.next();

} while(a=='Y'|| a=='y')
```

If the user enter's anything else, the loop will break. :)

Comment: `@user` As per requirement , If the user enter's anything else,User again ask for enter (Y/N) .

Comment: I guess the code can be modified accordingly by the person asking the question. We are here to give hints/ideas for such questions. The aim is not to meet all the "requirements".

Comment: `@user` I agree with you , But If we can do it easily so is more help full to questioner.

Comment: If we can do it easily, maybe the "questioner" can figure it out too. Much better to practice and learn than copy and paste the code.

Answer (score 2):

```
String awnser="";
do{

        int num,count=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input
        System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i <= (num/2); i++) 
        {
            if((num % i) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if((count==0) && (num!= 1))
        System.out.println( num + " is a prime number.");
        else
        System.out.println( num + " is not a prime number.");

        System.out.println("do you want to continue?");
        awnser=scan.next();

}while(awnser.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 1):

go with `switch case`

```
System.out.print("DO you to continue Y/N: ");
    String answer = scan.nextLine();


    switch (answer)
    {
    case "Y"
    case "y": //WRITE YOUR CODE HERE
             break;
    case "N"
    case "n"://exit from program;
             break;

    default :
             System.out.println("invalid choice")   ;
             break;
    }
```

Comment: You can only switch on int or Integer values

Answer (score 0):

How about using a while loop

```
while (!"N".equals(inputValues) {
//Keep asking for user inputs
```

}

Comment: `equalsIgnoreCase` would be a better catch...?

Answer (score 0):

You Can try this ..

```
import java.util.Scanner;

// importing package util

public class Prime
{
    static Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    static String userInput = null;

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        checkPrime();
        while (true)
        {
            System.out.print("Are You Want to Continue (Y/N) ?");
            userInput = scan.next();
            if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
                checkPrime();
            else if (userInput.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
            {
                System.out.print("Thank you !!");
                break;
            }
            else{
                            System.out.print("Try Again With (Y/N) only !");   
            }

        }

    }

    public static void checkPrime()
    {
        int num, count = 0;
        System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for (int i = 2; i <= (num / 2); i++)
        {
            if ((num % i) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if ((count == 0) && (num != 1))
            System.out.println(num + " is a prime number.");
        else
            System.out.println(num + " is not a prime number.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class example1 {
 static int value;
 static int quantity;
 static int total = 0;
 static int total_sold = 0;
 static int total_cashier = 0;
 static float expensier = 0;
 int again = 1;
 static String answer;

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  while (true) {
   System.out.print("Are You Want to Continue (Y/N) ?\n");
   Scanner ans = new Scanner(System.in);
   answer =ans.nextLine();
   if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Price: \n");
    value = input.nextInt();

    Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Input Quantity: \n");
    quantity = input2.nextInt();

    total += value * quantity;
    total_cashier += total;

    if (value > expensier) {
     expensier = value;
    }

    total_sold += quantity;

   } else if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("N")) {
    System.out.print("Thank you !!");
    break;
   } else {
    System.out.print("Try Again With (Y/N) only !");
   }
   System.out.println("Total to pay :" + total);
   System.out.println("Value of the expensiest product: " + expensier);
   System.out.println("Amount of products sold: " + total_sold);
   System.out.println("Amount of cash in cashier: " + total_cashier);

  }

 
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
  private static String reply;
     public static void main(String[] args){
         int num,count=0;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);
        do
{
 System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
        num = scan.nextInt();
        for(int i=2; i <= (num/2); i++) 
        {
            if((num % i) == 0)
            {
                count++;
                break;
            }
        }
        if((count==0) && (num!= 1))
        System.out.println( num + " is a prime number.");
        else
        System.out.println( num + " is not a prime number.");
        System.out.println("Continue(Y/N)");
         reply = scan.next().toUpperCase();

        } while(reply.equals("Y"));
```

I have notice only do while loop not prime no code...

Answer (score 0):

```
                package Loops;
                import java.util.Scanner;
                public class Question11 {
                    public static void main(String[] args) {
                        Scanner sc= new Scanner(System.in);
                        String a="";
                        do {
                            System.out.println("Enter the first number: \n");
                            int x = sc.nextInt();
                            System.out.println("Enter the second number: \n");
                            int y = sc.nextInt();
                            while (x < 0 || y < 0) {
                                System.out.println("Kindly enter the positive numbers: ");
                                x = sc.nextInt();
                                y = sc.nextInt();
                            }
                            int z = x + y;
                            System.out.println("The addition of 2 numbers is: " + z);
                            System.out.println("Do you want to do the addition again: press y or n");
                            a = sc.next();
                        }while (a.equals("y") || a.equals("Y"));
                        System.out.println("Thanks for using the application: ");
```

Answer (score -1):

use this code

```
import java.util.*; 

public class stackof
{
public static void main (String args[])
{
    int num,count=0;
    String s="y";
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); //scanner for input
    System.out.print("Enter any number : ");

    while(s.equalsIgnoreCase("y")){
        num = scan.nextInt();
      for(int i=2; i <= (num/2); i++)
      {
        if((num % i) == 0)
        {
            count++;
            break;
        }
      }

      if((count==0) && (num!= 1))
         System.out.println( num + " is a prime number.");
      else
         System.out.println( num + " is not a prime number.");

      System.out.println( "Do you want to enter another no?");
      s=scan.next();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 1- Why ("use this code") 2- Personally, I think a `do-while` loop would be more logical as you WANT to do the first loop, just saying ;)

Comment: Possibly take the time to indent your code. It's much easier to read that way.

Comment: yeah true,but this is just another method of solving her problem :)